# Not able to generate X Coordinates and Y coordinates Via using Formula

Tags: excel, alteryx

I am trying to create X and Y coordinates in Excel based on my first column which is 1- 100. I am not able to achieve the desired result.Attached Screenshot

I have only 1 column which is Path and based on that I need to derive X and Y. 
Note : Simple formula would suffice the needs. Not looking for VBA Code.

```
+------+------+----+
| Path |  Y   | X  |
+------+------+----+
|    1 |    1 |  1 |
|    2 |  0.5 |  2 |
|    3 |  1.5 |  2 |
|    4 |    0 |  3 |
|    5 |    1 |  3 |
|    6 |    2 |  3 |
|    7 | -0.5 |  4 |
|    8 |  0.5 |  4 |
|    9 |  1.5 |  4 |
|   10 |  2.5 |  4 |
|   11 |   -1 |  5 |
|   12 |    0 |  5 |
|   13 |    1 |  5 |
|   14 |    2 |  5 |
|   15 |    3 |  5 |
|   16 | -1.5 |  6 |
|   17 | -0.5 |  6 |
|   18 |  0.5 |  6 |
|   19 |  1.5 |  6 |
|   20 |  2.5 |  6 |
|   21 |  3.5 |  6 |
|   22 |   -2 |  7 |
|   23 |   -1 |  7 |
|   24 |    0 |  7 |
|   25 |    1 |  7 |
|   26 |    2 |  7 |
|   27 |    3 |  7 |
|   28 |    4 |  7 |
|   29 | -2.5 |  8 |
|   30 | -1.5 |  8 |
|   31 | -0.5 |  8 |
|   32 |  0.5 |  8 |
|   33 |  1.5 |  8 |
|   34 |  2.5 |  8 |
|   35 |  3.5 |  8 |
|   36 |  4.5 |  8 |
|   37 |   -3 |  9 |
|   38 |   -2 |  9 |
|   39 |   -1 |  9 |
|   40 |    0 |  9 |
|   41 |    1 |  9 |
|   42 |    2 |  9 |
|   43 |    3 |  9 |
|   44 |    4 |  9 |
|   45 |    5 |  9 |
|   46 | -3.5 | 10 |
|   47 | -2.5 | 10 |
|   48 | -1.5 | 10 |
|   49 | -0.5 | 10 |
|   50 |  0.5 | 10 |
|   51 |  1.5 | 10 |
|   52 |  2.5 | 10 |
|   53 |  3.5 | 10 |
|   54 |  4.5 | 10 |
|   55 |  5.5 | 10 |
|   56 |   -3 | 11 |
|   57 |   -2 | 11 |
|   58 |   -1 | 11 |
|   59 |    0 | 11 |
|   60 |    1 | 11 |
|   61 |    2 | 11 |
|   62 |    3 | 11 |
|   63 |    4 | 11 |
|   64 |    5 | 11 |
|   65 | -2.5 | 12 |
|   66 | -1.5 | 12 |
|   67 | -0.5 | 12 |
|   68 |  0.5 | 12 |
|   69 |  1.5 | 12 |
|   70 |  2.5 | 12 |
|   71 |  3.5 | 12 |
|   72 |  4.5 | 12 |
|   73 |   -2 | 13 |
|   74 |   -1 | 13 |
|   75 |    0 | 13 |
|   76 |    1 | 13 |
|   77 |    2 | 13 |
|   78 |    3 | 13 |
|   79 |    4 | 13 |
|   80 | -1.5 | 14 |
|   81 | -0.5 | 14 |
|   82 |  0.5 | 14 |
|   83 |  1.5 | 14 |
|   84 |  2.5 | 14 |
|   85 |  3.5 | 14 |
|   86 |   -1 | 15 |
|   87 |    0 | 15 |
|   88 |    1 | 15 |
|   89 |    2 | 15 |
|   90 |    3 | 15 |
|   91 | -0.5 | 16 |
|   92 |  0.5 | 16 |
|   93 |  1.5 | 16 |
|   94 |  2.5 | 16 |
|   95 |    0 | 17 |
|   96 |    1 | 17 |
|   97 |    2 | 17 |
|   98 |  0.5 | 18 |
|   99 |  1.5 | 18 |
|  100 |    1 | 19 |
+------+------+----+
```

Comment: You can get the x values from triangular numbers as far as row 55:

    =ROUNDUP((SQRT(1+8*A2)-1)/2,0)

That's all I feel like doing tonight - it's late here!

Comment: Thank you Tom for your answer .. It did solved the Problem till 55 for X . Any other way to force it to appear till 100?
Can we achieve the same way for Y as well at least for 55? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I have put this in my answer (I couldn't see a single single solution all the way up to 100, so it's basically a different formula for the second half using an if statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My formula for x in D2 is

```
=IF(A2<=50,ROUNDUP((SQRT(1+8*A2)-1)/2,0),20-ROUNDUP((SQRT(1+8*(101-A2))-1)/2,0))
```

and for y in E2 is

```
=IF(A2<=50,-0.5*(D2-1)+A2-(D2-1)*D2/2,-0.5*(19-D2)+A2-100+(20-D2)*(21-D2)/2)
```

(if you wanted to get y directly from Path, you would have to substitute the first formula for D2 all the way through the second formula).

[image]

These formulas come from the fact that the number of rows r up to the last appearance of a certain number n in the x column is a triangular number so:

```
r=n*(n+1)/2
```

and you can solve this for n to give the number in terms of the row:

```
n=(sqrt(1+8*r)-1)/2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are truly an amazing Mathematician.This wouldn't be possible without help.
I am just curious to know how you ended up with "20-ROUNDUP((SQRT(1+8*(101-A2))-1)/2". Whats your thought process?

Comment: You are welcome! I am in awe of proper mathematicians, just an amateur. Anyway I could see that the frequency of the x-values was symmetrical, going from 1 up to 10 then down again to 1. So if you start from the end and use 101-r instead of r, you get the same numbers 1,2,2,3,3,3... as at the beginning. So all you have to do is subtract these from 20 to get 19,18,18,17,17,17...

Comment: By the way, I would be interested to know the context of your question - was it just a brain-teaser or was there some other reason behind it?

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation. Actually I am creating a Square Pie Chart in tableau .The reason why I am looking for generic X and Y is because I am using high volume of data (55 Millions) where I cannot use Excel sheet for blending/Joining. So I modified the formula(Created bins and Table Calculation) based on my needs . I also did some research based on you Advice which can be found here //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number